# Ajax not loading success in JSONP call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I'm a little stuck here. I'm trying to get JSON data (tweets from the Twitter API) from a PHP script via JSONP and Ajax. The class (TwitterProxy) don't have the trouble because the data arrives fine from the PHP, I can see the JSON in the response with the developer tools of Firefox but the success method doesn't load.

Firefox (failed to load script) and Chrome (net::ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR) give me an error too, besides the error function give me a 404 error code in Chrome. Any ideas?

You can try it here writing nasa:
http://diegovelserver.epizy.com/

The Javascript

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.btn').click(function (){
        showNSave();
    });
    $('.user').bind("enterKey", function (){
        showNSave();
    });
    $('.user').keyup(function (e){
        if(e.keyCode == 13) {
            $(this).trigger("enterKey");
        }
    });
});

function showNSave () {
    doRequest($('.user').val());

}

function doRequest (user){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://diegovelserver.000webhostapp.com/php/app.php',
        type:'GET',
        data: {data: user},
        jsonp: "callback",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data){
            alert("success");
            $('.jsonpResult').html(data);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log(e.responseType);
            console.log(e.status);
        }
    });
}
```

The PHP

```js
<?php


class TwitterProxy
{
    private $config = [
        'use_whitelist' => false, // Marcar false para permitir conexiones ajenas a Twitter
        'base_url' => 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/'
    ];

    private $whitelist = [];

    public function __construct($oauth_access_token, $oauth_access_token_secret, $consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $screen_name, $count = 5)
    {
        $this->config = array_merge($this->config, compact('oauth_access_token', 'oauth_access_token_secret', 'consumer_key', 'consumer_secret', 'user_id', 'screen_name', 'count'));

        $this->whitelist['statuses/user_timeline.json?' . 'screen_name=' . $this->config['screen_name'] . '&count=' . $this->config['count']] = true;
    }

    private function buildBaseString($baseURI, $method, $params)
    {
        $r = [];
        ksort($params);
        foreach ($params as $key=>$value) {
            $r[] = "$key=" . rawurlencode($value);
        }

        return $method . "&" . rawurlencode($baseURI) . '&' . rawurlencode(implode('&', $r));
    }

    private function setOauthKeys(){
        print_r($this->config);
    }

    private function buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth)
    {
        $r = 'Authorization: OAuth ';
        $values = [];
        foreach ($oauth as $key => $value) {
            $values[] = "$key=\"" . rawurlencode($value) . "\"";
        }
        $r .= implode(', ', $values);

        return $r;
    }

    public function get($url)
    {
        if (! isset($url)) {
            die('No URL set');
        }

        if ($this->config['use_whitelist'] && ! isset($this->whitelist[$url])) {
            die('URL is not authorised');
        }

        $url_parts = parse_url($url);
        parse_str($url_parts['query'], $url_arguments);

        $full_url = $this->config['base_url'] . $url;
        $base_url = $this->config['base_url'] . $url_parts['path'];

        $oauth = [
            'oauth_consumer_key' => $this->config['consumer_key'],
            'oauth_nonce' => time(),
            'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
            'oauth_token' => $this->config['oauth_access_token'],
            'oauth_timestamp' => time(),
            'oauth_version' => '1.0'
        ];

        $base_info = $this->buildBaseString($base_url, 'GET', array_merge($oauth, $url_arguments));


        $composite_key = rawurlencode($this->config['consumer_secret']) . '&' . rawurlencode($this->config['oauth_access_token_secret']);

        $oauth['oauth_signature'] = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base_info, $composite_key, true));

        $header = [
            $this->buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth),
            'Expect:'
        ];
        $options = [
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
            //CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postfields,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
            CURLOPT_URL => $full_url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
        ];

        $feed = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($feed, $options);
        $result = curl_exec($feed);
        $info = curl_getinfo($feed);
        curl_close($feed);

        if (isset($info['content_type']) && isset($info['size_download'])) {
            header('Content-Type: ' . $info['content_type']);
            header('Content-Length: ' . $info['size_download']);
        }

        return $result;
    }
}

//----------------------------------------------------troubles begins here------
$user = $_GET['data'];

$twitterConexion = new TwitterProxy(
    '913141342070542337-1eFZgaABcUpCIP8M4n95f2kSxdnWLtL',
    'ElpTj4OvHMiNN8mlTOKplOp8RZR70ZC7cyUJqQymwumPP',
    'HR9fwpQuYwqzIY7mh2ZNqM59F',
    'CasF1JnHDGo9rjYlXKvUeUboeKovmzSGVEBNAYiD1JJRC4mSkb',
    $user,
    1);

$twitter_url = 'statuses/user_timeline.json';
$twitter_url .= '?screen_name=' . $user;
$twitter_url .= '&count=3';

$tweets = $twitterConexion->get( $twitter_url );

echo json_encode($tweets);

?>
```

Comment: If you visit the URL you're calling it appears to show a PHP error relating to 'headers alredy being sent'

Comment: It's weird because if I try whit this:
https://diegovelserver.000webhostapp.com/php/app.php?user=nasa
gives me the 'headers already being sent'

But if I try with this:
https://diegovelserver.000webhostapp.com/php/app.php?data=nasa
gives me the JSON. 

However, I try to change the $_GET['data'] in the PHP for  $_GET['user'] but there's no change

Comment: Maybe a server error?

Comment: In the case that 'works' you should note that the format of the JSON is not correct. Also note that it's attempting to return JSON, not JSONP, so a cross-domain request will not work.

Comment: I thought that the PHP had to return the JSON but if not how I can get the JSON?
Did I want to ask too, I not need the headers in the PHP file?